# How to add more pincodes in Cash on Delivery restriction module?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento1.9.3, cash-on-delivery, pincodes

I am using custom module Cash on delivery restriction by zipcodes for Magento 1.9.3.7

[image]
I am having an issue to add pincodes more than 10 thousand. This module only accepts 8 thousand pincodes.

here is Observer class

```
class Mfp_Cod_Model_Observer
{
    public function getCashOnDelvery(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event           = $observer->getEvent();
        $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
        $result          = $event->getResult();
        $isModuleEnable  = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/enable');

        if ($isModuleEnable) {
            if ($method->getCode() == 'phoenix_cashondelivery' ) {
                $quote          = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $add            = $quote->getShippingAddress();
                $postcode       = $add->getData('postcode');
                $comparisonMode = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/mode');
                $zipCodes       = Mage::getStoreConfig('cod/cod/zipcode');
                $isExist        = false;

                if (trim($zipCodes) == '') {
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                } else {
                    if (strpos($zipCodes, $postcode) !==  false) {
                        $isExist = true;
                    }

                    if ($isExist != true) {
                        $zipCodesArray = explode(',', nl2br($zipCodes));
                        if (count($elementLineArray) > 1) {
                            foreach ($zipCodesArray as $codzipLine) {
                                $elementLineArray = explode('-', $codzipLine);
                                if (count($elementLineArray) == 2 && ( $postcode >= $elementLineArray[0] && $postcode <= $elementLineArray[1] )) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                } else if ($postcode == $codzipLine) {
                                    $isExist = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $returnValue = '';
                    $returnValue = ($isExist)?true:false;

                    $result->isAvailable = $returnValue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue. is there any limitation for data saving. How can I add more than 10 thousand zipcodes?

Answer (score 4):

I would **not** change the column tpye to `LONGTEXT` for `core_config_data` table, because it could have a negative impact on performance.

If I had to save such a large number of zipcode I would

- add a new DB table `cod_zipcodes` and
- a new admin grid to maintain them.

It's bit more work then adding a new config field, but you dont have alter DB structure and in your observer you just have to check if the zipcode exists in your table, instead of iterating over an 10k size array.

Comment: This approach is good. I like to hear your comment on my approach.

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV it would be my 2nd choice :) If you want to manage it from backend or config you also have to add a source model. So there is still some additional work ... +1 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) yes additional work is required but it's a reliable solution isn't it ? If there is anything wrong in that approach I request to correct it. Based on that I can suggest or don't recommend it as a solution to others

Comment: @KalyanChakravarthiV Haven't tested it, but i think there is nothing wrong with your approach. :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of saving the pincodes in the database, I suggest using a file to save all your pincodes. It can be CSV file or XML file or JSON file. You can use respective handler based on the file format. In your observer read the file and extract the values and compare. This way there is no need to do any DB level changes.

In admin settings, in the place of Zipcodes keep the file upload option.

Here is an example to read XML file from the source ( http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-read-write-xml/ )

```
$xmlPath = Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'test.xml';
$xmlObj = new Varien_Simplexml_Config($xmlPath);
$xmlData = $xmlObj->getNode();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($xmlData); echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your core_config_data database table value column is having "text" datatype, you need to alter the table.

ALTER TABLE core_config_data MODIFY value MEDIUMTEXT; (It will store 16,777,215 - 16 MB)

or

ALTER TABLE core_config_data MODIFY value LONGTEXT; (It will store 4,294,967,295 characters - 4 GB)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I Think there are no issues on code maybe it's executed `max_input_vars`. You just need to open your server's php.ini file with root user, search for `max_input_vars` and set its value as `100000` and it will solve your problem.

```
max_input_vars = 100000
```

I hope it'll help you to resolve your problem.